# Stream Debug in IntelliJ IDEA (java)

Tags: java, stream

I have this code with Stream I want to debug.
I run Debug mode and Click the Trace Current Stream Chain button in the Debug tool window
Then  the Stream trace window opens, though I have an Internal error instead of evaluated results.

(Community Edition 2020.3)

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    String input = "Speedment";

    String result = Stream.of(input.split(""))
            .map(s -> s.charAt(0))
            .sorted()
            .limit(5)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(joining());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I pressed Flat mode button and it works!

The reason is that there are too many operations in stream and memory of notebook is not sufficient.